# Find four sets of coins with similar weights

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, puzzle

There are $n\geq 4$ coins. You are allowed to ask for the weight of any set of coins. What is the worst-case (asymptotic) minimum number of questions after which you can divide the coins into four sets with the property that between any two sets $A,B$, there exists a coin in $B$ that if you remove it, then $A$ weights at least as much as $B$?

Such a division exists by this simple algorithm: for each coin, place it in the pile with the minimum weight so far. By using $n$ questions, we can ask for the weight of each coin individually and get full information. If all coins has weight either $0$ or $1$, then we can do binary search three times to divide the coins into four sets using $O(\log n)$ questions.

Comment: Is this research-level mathematics?

Comment: There are other coin puzzles posted on this site, e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151390/how-to-find-counterfeit-coins-by-weighing) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198847/neighborly-family-of-coins). If those are appropriate questions for the site, I don't see how this one isn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $O(\log n)$ questions will still suffice. I would first, weigh all the coins, then, using binary search, divide the coins into four groups, $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ and $O(1)$ additional coins such that by adding them to the groups we can make any $A_i$ the lightest. Doing this requires some case analysis. ps. Why the magic number four?